# why is this expression used when using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

why is this if is used when used requestAnimationFrame??

```js
if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
              timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };
```

Comment: Are you asking why an existing piece of code written by someone else is written a certain way? Then please edit your question to add the context—where did you find this code, and what is the overall code used for? If this isn't what you're asking, then it's too unclear what you want to ask, so again you should edit your question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That piece of code implements requestAnimationFrame. It defines a global function `requestAnimationFrame` (all members of `window` are global variables) if such a function doesn't exist.

Here's a short explanation via comments of what it does:

```
if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) // if requestAnimationFrame doesn't exist
  window.requestAnimationFrame = 
    function(callback, element) { // define requestAnimationFrame
      /* implementation detail */
    };
```

Such pieces of code are known as polyfills - code that implement features of newer versions of the browser/javascript engine in older browsers/javascript engines.

Comment: Note that since polyfills are written in javascript itself it may not be as fast as a natively implemented function which may be written in C. But the whole point of polyfills is to allow you to use new features in old browsers.